# Dynamic database connection symfony2

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine-orm

My symfony2 project has a main database and many child databases. Each child database is created for each user, the database credentials are stored in the main database. When the user logins, the user specific database credentials are fetched from the main database and the child database connection ideally should be established.
I googled for the same, and I came accross a number of solutions and finally did the following:

```
#config.yml

doctrine:
dbal:
    default_connection:       default
    connections:
        default:
            dbname:           maindb
            user:             root
            password:         null
            host:             localhost
        dynamic_conn:
            dbname:           ~
            user:             ~
            password:         ~
            host:             localhost
orm:
    default_entity_manager:   default
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection:       default
            auto_mapping:     true
        dynamic_em:
            connection:       dynamic_conn
            auto_mapping:     true
```

I created a default connection to connect to the main database and an empty connection for the child database, similarly I created entity managers.
Then I created default event listener and added the following code to the 'onKernelRequest':

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) //works like preDispatch in Zend
{
    //code to get db credentials from master database and stored in varaiables
    ....
    $connection = $this->container->get(sprintf('doctrine.dbal.%s_connection', 'dynamic_conn'));
    $connection->close();

    $refConn = new \ReflectionObject($connection);
    $refParams = $refConn->getProperty('_params');
    $refParams->setAccessible('public'); //we have to change it for a moment

    $params = $refParams->getValue($connection);
    $params['dbname'] = $dbName;
    $params['user'] = $dbUser;
    $params['password'] = $dbPass;

    $refParams->setAccessible('private');
    $refParams->setValue($connection, $params);
    $this->container->get('doctrine')->resetEntityManager('dynamic_em');
    ....
}
```

The above code sets the child database parameters and resets the dynamic_em entity manager.

When I do the following in some controller, it works fine and the data if fetched from the child database.

```
$getblog= $em->getRepository('BloggerBlogBundle:Blog')->findById($id); //uses doctrine
```

But, when I use security context as seen in the following code, I get an error 'NO DATABASE SELECTED'.

```
$securityContext = $this->container->get('security.context');
$loggedinUserid = $securityContext->getToken()->getUser()->getId();
```

**How can I set database connection dynamically and use security context as well?**

**UPDATE:-**

After much time spent on trial and error, and googling around, I realized that `security.context` is set before the execution of `onKernelRequest`. Now the question is **how** to inject the database connection details into the security.context, and **where** to inject?

We need to get to a point where the DBAL and security context is set and security token is created, and we can manipulate database connection details.

Hence, as the person in the following link stated, I made changes to my code, as thats exactly what I would want to do.
http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=37398&p=124413

That leaves me the following code add to my project:

```
#config.yml //remains unchanged, similar to above code
```

A compiler pass is created as follows:

```
// src/Blogger/BlogBundle/BloggerBlogBundle.php
namespace Blogger\BlogBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

use Blogger\BlogBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CustomCompilerPass;

class BloggerBlogBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);

        $container->addCompilerPass(new CustomCompilerPass());
    }
}
```

The compiler pass is as follows:

```
# src/Blogger/BlogBundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CustomCompilerPass.php

class CustomCompilerPassimplements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $connection_service = 'doctrine.dbal.dynamic_conn_connection';
        if ($container->hasDefinition($connection_service))
        {
            $def = $container->getDefinition($connection_service);
            $args = $def->getArguments();
            $args[0]['driverClass'] = 'Blogger\BlogBundle\UserDependentMySqlDriver';
            $args[0]['driverOptions'][] = array(new Reference('security.context'));
            $def->replaceArgument(0, $args[0]);
        }
   }
}
```

The driver class code is as follows:

```
# src/Blogger/BlogBundle/UserDependentMySqlDriver.php

use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver;

class UserDependentMySqlDriver extends Driver
{    
    public function connect(array $params, $username = null, $password = null, array $driverOptions = array())
    {
        $dbname = .....  //store database name in variable
        $params['dbname'] = $dbname;
        return parent::connect($params, $username, $password, array());
    }
}
```

The above code were added to my project, and I assume that this is the actual work around for to my problem.

But now I get the following error:

> ServiceCircularReferenceException: Circular reference detected for
>   service "security.context", path: "profiler_listener -> profiler ->
>   security.context -> security.authentication.manager ->
>   fos_user.user_provider.username_email -> fos_user.user_manager ->
>   doctrine.orm.dynamic_manager_entity_manager ->
>   doctrine.dbal.dynamic_conn_connection".

How, can I get my code to work? I bet that I am doing something wrong here and I would appreciate any hints and help.

Comment: is the code using the `security.context` ran *before* the `onKernelRequest` event ? some dependency of security.context must be using the `dynamic_em`

Comment: The security.context code is added to the same action where the getRespository code is added. Hence I assume, that the onKernelRequest is executed before the security.context.

Comment: @John I just tested it with Sf 2.3.2 and your first solution works for me. I used an event subscriber to modify the connection object. The controller later on fetched a row from the "slave" database and loaded the currently logged in user (used `FOSUserBundle`). The security context does get populated during the event dispatching phase and at first glance I thought it was simply a matter of changing listener priorities. If you haven't already figured it out then perhaps you could tell me which Symfony version are you using?

Comment: Had the same issue, without security.context (users are stored in _child_ dbs). CompilerPass and *MySqlDriver did the trick

Comment: There are very good solutions to this problem posted here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108732/symfony2-dynamic-db-connection-early-override-of-doctrine-service/24585284#24585284

Answer (score 5):

Here, you need to implement your own logic on your own, in your own business.

Take a look at documentation of Doctrine on "how to create an entity manager".

Then create a service with a clear API:

```
$this->get('em_factory')->getManager('name-of-my-client'); // returns an EntityManager
```

You can't do it with default DoctrineBundle, it's not usable for dynamic features.

```
class EmFactory
{
    public function getManager($name)
    {
        // you can get those values:
        // - autoguess, based on name
        // - injection through constructor
        // - other database connection
        // just create constructor and inject what you need
        $params = array('username' => $name, 'password' => $name, ....);

        // get an EM up and running
        // see http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html#obtaining-the-entitymanager

        return $em;
    }
}
```

And declare as a service.

Comment: I like this answer more than mine. It much more well aligned.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to propose different solution to your original problem.You can use [PhpFileLoader](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/PhpFileLoader.html) to dynamically define parameters for your config.yml.

1. Extract you main database connection parameters into separate file:

   ```
   # src/Blogger/BlogBundle/Resources/config/parameters.yml

   parameters:
       main_db_name:           maindb
       main_db_user:           root
       main_db_password:       null
       main_db_host:           localhost
   ```
2. Create new PHP script (say DynamicParametersLoader.php) which will inject new parameters in app container. I think you cannot use your symfony app in this script, but you can read main db credentials from $container variable. Like the following:

   ```
   # src/Blogger/BlogBundle/DependecyInjection/DynamicParametersLoader.php
   <?php

   $mainDbName = $container->getParameter('main_db_name'); 
   $mainDbUser = $container->getParameter('main_db_user');
   $mainDbPassword = $container->getParameter('main_db_password');
   $mainDbHost = $container->getParameter('main_db_host');

   # whatever code to query your main database for dynamic DB credentials. You cannot use your symfony2 app services here, so it ought to be plain PHP.
   ...

   # creating new parameters in container
   $container->setParameter('dynamic_db_name', $dbName);
   $container->setParameter('dynamic_db_user', $dbUser);
   $container->setParameter('dynamic_db_password', $dbPass);
   ```
3. Now you need to tell Symfony about your script and new parameters.yml file:

   ```
   # config.yml
   imports:
       - { resource: parameters.yml }
       - { resource: ../../DependencyInjection/DynamicParametersLoader.php }
   ```
4. At this step you can freely use injected parameters in you config:

   ```
   # config.yml
   ...
           dynamic_conn:
               dbname:           %dynamic_db_name%
               user:             %dynamic_db_user%
               password:         %dynamic_db_password%
   ...
   ```

Comment: This solution will not work because parameters are already replaced in placeholders. Also, you will regenerate a new container each time you need to change. It will be a performance murder.

Comment: Alexandre, there are different parameters in placeholders (dynamic_db_name vs main_db_name).

Comment: my dynamic_db_name is based on url, and in DynamicParametersLoader.php I get it from url and use in connection.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very good solution using an event listener posted here:

[Symfony2, Dynamic DB Connection/Early override of Doctrine Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108732/symfony2-dynamic-db-connection-early-override-of-doctrine-service/24585284#24585284)