# Access current subdomain in config.yml

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a simple Symfony2 app that needs to connect to a particular database based on the subdomain. Database names are the same as subdomain names.

Domain: `alpha.example.com` - DB name: `alpha`

Domain: `beta.example.com` - DB name: `beta`

The most simple way to achieve this, as I think of it, is to pass current subdomain into the `config.yml` file

```
#config.yml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "current-subdomain-name-here"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
```

The question is how to pass & access current subdomain name in `config.yml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd avoid putting this into `app.php`. Maybe you need the same code also in `app_dev.php` for development and testing.

One config file per subdomain looks not very convenient too.

Take a look at:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/external_parameters.html#miscellaneous-configuration

There you could do something like (not tested):

```
# app/config/config.yml
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.php }
```

-

```
// app/config/parameters.php
$subdomain = array_shift((explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])));
$container->setParameter('doctrine.dbal.dbname', $subdomain);
```

Comment: Wow, didn't know about that. Very useful. This would also work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible but in any case the configuration files shouldn't never contain any application logic.

You can follow the directives explained in the cookbook about [multiple managers and connections](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html) and then create the logic (using the dependancy injection services for instance) but the implementation depends by your specific use case of which I don't know nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't want to do this in the config.yml.  Rather, you should hook into the Kernel request and set your connection there.  Check out the accepted answer to this post:

[Symfony2, Dynamic DB Connection/Early override of Doctrine Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108732/symfony2-dynamic-db-connection-early-override-of-doctrine-service)

You can then just use `$this->request->getHost()` in your listener, parse out the subdomain, and open a connection to your database after passing the subdomain's name as the `dbname` parameter.  For example (not tested):

```
public function onKernelRequest()
{
    // this might cause issues if there is no subdomain, might need regex...just an example
    $dbname = array_shift(explode('.', $this->request->getHost()));
    $params = $this->connection->getParams();

    if ($dbname !== $params['dbname'])
    {
        $this->connection->close();

        $this->connection = new Connection()
            $params,
            $this->connection->getDriver(),
            $this->connection->getConfiguration(),
            $this->connection->getEventManager()
        );

        try {
            $this->connection->connect();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // log and handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my own challenge in the following way.

I created different config files for each subdomain. In my case, I have a limited number of subdomains.

```
#config.yml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
```

Config for subdomain `alpha.example.com`:

```
#config_alpha.yml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        dbname:   "alpha"
```

Config for subdomain `beta.example.com`:

```
#config_beta.yml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        dbname:   "beta"
```

In the `app.php` we determine the subdomain, and load the corresponding config:

```
// web/app.php
// ...
$subdomain = array_shift((explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])));
// In case of alpha.example.com
// $subdomain = "alpha"
// Its going to load config_alpha.yml
$kernel = new AppKernel($subdomain, true);
// ...
```