# FOSUserbundle and multiple database connections in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, multiple-databases

I am working on a Symfony2 Application that uses multiple databases. I followed this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24585284/5244717 so now all my routes have a prefix with the database name from where the application should get its data.

But now I need to be able to login, I tried using the FOSUserbundle, but I cannot get FOSUserbundle to work with the company prefix. I added this to the config/routing.yml

```
fos_user_security:
resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"
prefix: /{_site}
defaults:
     _site: default
```

Now when I go to http://localhost/company/login it shows me the login form, but when I login it gives me this error:

> You must configure the check path to be handled by the firewall using form_login in your security firewall configuration.

I have no idea how to fix this and if the FOSUserbundle will even work with what I am trying to do here. Having used Symfony2 only for week is not really helping. I've been searching the internet for a good solution to using multiple databases in 1 symfony bundle but so far have had little success. Each company should get a separate database with the same structure, but this seems to be an impossible thing to code in Symfony2(or any other framework).

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your options but not limited to

1). have multiple firewalls

2). use of subdomains instead of slugs in url

i could be wrong but i believe symfony does not allow parameters to be set in a route for a login page